# Does FileStream include track changes for MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, filestream

I'm trying to save a MS Word document (which contains some track changes already) to my database.
The steps I follow goes like this:

1. Get a file stream of the MS Word document
2. Convert the file stream to a byte array
3. Encrypt the byte array and save to database

It seems to be working fine because the document is saved correctly to the database. However it does not take across the track changes, i.e. it saves the entire document to the database but when I re-open the document from the database I cannot track what changes was made previously anymore, even thought the text changes I made shows in the document.

Does `FileStream` on MS Word include track changes? Or is there something obvious that I am missing

Comment: filestream shouldnt change the file in any way, so if tracked changes are in there, they should remain - just like mailing them. Filestream is not file content aware so I would certainly not expect only a small portion to change, Id expect it to be total garbage as something went wrong, or entirely right

Comment: Please post your code. As BugFinder said, the `FileStream` class treats the file as a whole and does not remove any Word features as it is not aware of the file format details. So my guess is that your code is doing something different than you tell us.